# Windows keyboard shortcut force always open new window

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a shortcut on my desktop for a command that runs `cmd.exe /k <myscript.cmd>`. I assigned it the keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

This works to open one window, but the problem is that pressing the shortcut a second time switches focus to the window that's already open. I would like a new window to be created each time I press the shortcut instead of switching focus to the existing window.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try using [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your shortcut to

```
start myscript.cmd
```

From the [Microsoft Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx): The `start` command will start a separate Command Prompt window to run a specified program or command.

---

If your command name contains space(s)
(e.g., `C:\Program Files\mystuff\myscript.cmd`),
you need to put it into quotes, of course. 
Because of a quirk in the user interface design for the `start` command,
if you do this, you need to provide *another* quoted string first. 
This is intended to set the title of the new window, so you could say,

```
start "This is mine!" "C:\Program Files\mystuff\myscript.cmd"
```

or you can just leave it blank:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\mystuff\myscript.cmd"
```

Comment: Tried this and thought it didn't work, but it turned out I had to close the other window previously opened with the shortcut. After that, opening multiple new windows works.

Comment: Hi @Fred, I see your edit here, did you _need_ to use the full path to `cmd.exe`? It should be on your path by default and not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The exact shortcut target reads:

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "start myscript.cmd arg1 arg2"`

It did not work with quotes around the "myscript.cmd...".